# Xcode Launch Screen black screen for kivymd project

Tags: xcode, kivy, kivymd, launch-screen

I have an existing KivyMD app which I changed the launch image to launchscreen.storyboard, because the old launch image method is no longer supported in Xcode. I created the launchscreen.storyboard under the root directory. When it runs, it flashed the launch image and went to black screen for a few seconds, before the home page of the app. The app ran fine without issue. The black screen is consistent across simulator and device. I noticed it shows below dlopen Foundation error during launch, I don't know how to fix it. Help please.

Got dlopen error on Foundation: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation, 0x0001): tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2, not in dyld cache)
Got fallback dlopen error on Foundation: dlopen(/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation, 0x0001): tried: '/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), '/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2, not in dyld cache)

[image]

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of the Launch Screen setup of your target?

Comment: Thanks for quick response! - I attached the screen. BTW, xcode version is 14.3

Answer (score 0):

After research and test, I overcome the issue. By changing the 'Launch Screen Interface file base name' attribute under Targets > Info > Custom ios target properties. As per screen, this is after, the working one. Before, the value is Launch Screen.storyboard. I deleted the .storyboard. It worked. [image]